# why the all the coefficient terms of this integral share the least common factor 1/594

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

why the all the coefficient terms of this integral share the least common factor 1/594?

Refer to this: $\int 1/(x^{23}+x^{50}) dx$

There are a lot of weird terms in the answer but they all share the least common factor 1/594

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1%2F%28x%5E23%2Bx%5E50%29

edit 1: How to derive the least common factor 1/594 if that is a math competition problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int 1/(x^{23}+x^{50}) dx=\int \frac{x^4}{x^{27}+x^{54}} dx$$

Now 
$$\frac{1}{x^{27}+x^{54}}=\frac{1}{x^{27}(x^{27}+1)}=\frac{1}{x^{27}}-\frac{1}{x^{27}+1}$$

This Yields
$$=\int \frac{x^4}{x^{27}+x^{54}} dx=\int \frac{x^4}{x^{27}}dx+\int \frac{x^4}{x^{27}+1} dx$$

The first integral is easy to calculate, while for the second, unless I am missing something simple, you write the denominator as product of terms of the form $(x-\omega_k)$ where $\omega_k$ are the relevant $54$ roots of unity. Then you either do PFD (partial fraction decomposition) over complex numbers, or group them in pairs of conjugates and do PFD.

You don't need to actually calculate everything, just keep track of denominators.

Comment: May i ask you how to finish the rest step?

Comment: $$\frac{x^4}{x^{27}+1}=\sum \frac{A_k}{x-\omega_k} \Rightarrow X^4 = \sum A_k(X-\omega_1)..(X-\omega_{k-1})(X-\omega_{k+1})...(X-\omega_{27})$$ Now, if you plug in $x=\omega_k$ you get $$A_k=\frac{\omega_k^4}{(\omega_k-\omega_1)..(\omega_k-\omega_{k-1})(\omega_k- \omega_{k+1})(\omega_k-\omega_{27})}$$.

Comment: Appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of fractions in the integral; some have $27$ in the denominator and some have $22$; the least common multiple is $594$.  Alpha has pulled out the common factor.